# How to show time based event in Calendar - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, calendar, flutter-layout, timeslots

I'm creating an app for **Grounds** in which you can book a ground from a time slot.

I have to create UI like the below image

[image]

From the top right corner, the user picks a time range and It'll show only those dates available in the **calendar** below.

The Red and Orange colors available in the calendar will be from APIs and it indicates already booked time slots.

**Does anyone have an idea that how to create UI like this or which package should i use?**

Comment: You can use https://pub.dev/packages/calendar_view package

Comment: Try this package: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_heatmap_calendar